# How to load unstructured data like images & videos into Hadoop distributed file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to load unstructured data(images,videos) into HDFS using hadoop components.Anyone can help me in this query.

Which hadoop component, I need to use in loading the unstructured data.

And using that component, how to import it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing and processing of Unstructured Data in Hadoop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198842/storing-and-processing-of-unstructured-data-in-hadoop)

Answer (score 1):

Unstructured data as in regular files?  If data is stored on a normal filesystem somewhere, then you don't need any fancy components.  You can upload it using built-in HDFS tools (`hadoop fs` etc.).  You can write some shell scripts to automate this...

If for some reason your data is stored as blobs in a database, you can use Sqoop.

Comment: thanks for the information...

If you have any references about dealing with unstructured data.. Please share with me. Any sample example on unstructured data.

Comment: Apart from using the built-in HDFS tools...I need information on Sqoop..How to import the unstructured data like images,video clips from database to HDFS..

Comment: Copying files to HDFS from the shell is really simple, here is one short tutorial: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/bigins/v2r0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.import.doc/doc/data_rest_shell.html .

Comment: Now, Sqoop is a little more complicated, but once you scan through the user guide it should be relatively straightforward.  Copying BLOBs is not significantly more different than any other data.  Here is a link to the Sqoop user guide:  https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects .

Comment: Thanks Daniel..I am aware of importing data from local path to HDFS path..But I want to know, Anyother way we can use to import the Unstructured data into the HDFS.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other methods.  Perhaps if you clarified why plain copying doesn't work for you, it would be of some help.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..I need one more information about HDFS..Normally after installation of hadoop, /User/hadoop partition will form..I need to know how to check the disksize of /user/hadoop and what is this partition exactly stands for.From which logical volume this partition belongs to..

Comment: You can check it using `hadoop fs du -s -h /user/hadoop` command, see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du .  HDFS will spread actual data around your cluster, so it will not necessarily be mapped to a single location on some machine.  You can look up where HDFS stores data on data node's local file system by consulting `dfs.data.dir` in `hdfs-default.xml` or `hdfs-site.xml` in your hadoop configuration directory.

Comment: Thanks daniel..I need more information about following parameters          Cluster Summary
3482 files and directories, 1620 blocks = 5102 total. Heap Size is 59.75 MB / 889 MB (6%)
Configured Capacity : 298.18 GB
DFS Used : 2.08 GB
Non DFS Used : 45.5 GB
DFS Remaining : 250.6 GB
DFS Used% : 0.7 %
DFS Remaining% : 84.04 %                         what is Non DFS used,DFS remining

Comment: Thanks Daniel..please differentiate the paramter Non DFS Used and  DFS Remaining..  I am pasting my cluster summary output           3482 files and directories, 1620 blocks = 5102 total. Heap Size is 59.75 MB / 889 MB (6%)
Configured Capacity : 298.18 GB
DFS Used : 2.08 GB
Non DFS Used : 45.5 GB
DFS Remaining : 250.6 GB
DFS Used% : 0.7 %
DFS Remaining% : 84.04 %
Live Nodes  : 4
Dead Nodes  : 1
Decommissioning Nodes  : 0
Number of Under-Replicated Blocks : 170                  I want to know how HDFS will allocate diskspace to /user/hadoop partition from local...Need simple answer for this..

Comment: I recommend you submit another question for this, as it is now getting quite off-topic relative to the original question.